# What is the lexically correct statement in Velocity Template Language

Tags: templates, velocity, vtl

The following line of code is a generic version of a line in a template I'm working on. I have looked at the Velocity Template Language [Documentation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#relational-and-logical-operators) but I keep getting errors no matter how I format this statement. This is my first real experience with VTL so I was hoping to get a set of experienced eyes on the issue:

```
#set($includeAttributes = 
   ${firstResponseItem.attribute1} != null || 
   ${firstResponseItem.attribute2 != null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `null` in Velocity, but you can check for a null value as if it was boolean `false`:

```
#set($includeAttributes = $firstResponseItem.attribute1 || $firstResponseItem.attribute2)
```